# Why do some Reactor operators request far more elements than they are interested in?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have the following code:

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.<String>never()
        .doOnRequest(n -> System.out.println("Requested " + n));
```

It is a Flux that never emits any signal, but reports demand to the console.

Each of the following 3 lines

```
flux.take(3).next().block();
flux.next().block();
flux.blockFirst();
```

produces this output:

```
Requested 9223372036854775807
```

Looking at the code, I see the following.

`BlockingSingleSubscriber` (works both in the cases of `Flux#blockFirst()` and `Mono#block()`:

```
public final void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
    this.s = s;
    if (!cancelled) {
        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

`MonoNext.NextSubscriber`:

```
public void request(long n) {
    if (WIP.compareAndSet(this, 0, 1)) {
        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

`FluxTake.TakeSubscriber`:

```
public void request(long n) {
    if (wip == 0 && WIP.compareAndSet(this, 0, 1)) {
        if (n >= this.n) {
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } else {
            s.request(n);
        }
        return;
    }

    s.request(n);
}
```

So `Flux#blockFirst()`, `Flux#next()` and `Mono#block()` always signal an unbounded demand to their upstream, and `Flux#take()` can do the same under some circumstances.

But `Flux#blockFirst()`, `Flux#next()` and `Mono#block()` each need at max one element from their upstream, and `Flux#take()` needs maximally this.n.

Also, `Flux#take()` javadoc says the following:

> Note that this operator doesn't manipulate the backpressure requested amount.
> Rather, it merely lets requests from downstream propagate as is and cancels once
> N elements have been emitted. As a result, the source could produce a lot of
> extraneous elements in the meantime. If that behavior is undesirable and you do
> not own the request from downstream (e.g. prefetching operators), consider
> using {@link #limitRequest(long)} instead.

The question is: why do they signal an unbounded demand when they know the limit upfront? I had an impression that reactive backpressure was about only asking for what you are ready to consume. But in reality, it often works like this: shout 'produce all you can' to the upstream, and then cancel the subscription once satisfied. In cases when it is costly to produce gazillion records upstream this seems simply wasteful.

Comment: Each operator only processes only one upstream event at a time. From the reactive manifesto, "It is RECOMMENDED that Subscribers request the upper limit of what they are able to process, as requesting only one element at a time results in an inherently inefficient "stop-and-wait" protocol.".

Comment: Basically downstream operators demand such a huge amount because they don't want the publisher to wait for a demand from downstream.

Comment: @PrashantPandey please note that all the operators I mentioned in my question have a **hard** limit on their possible demand. What sense does it make to request more than one element if you are **guaranteed** to only need one?

Comment: Note that not all operators place an unbounded demand. flatMap for instance places a demand for 256, and replinishes it when 75% of the elements have been processed. "What sense does it make to request more than one element if you are guaranteed to only need one" - As the manifesto says, requesting only one element from upstream turns it into a stop-and-wait protocol.

Comment: @PrashantPandey requesting elements one by one turns it into a stop-and-wait protocol in a *general* case, when you don't know how much you will need upfront. But when you are sure upfront that you will only need ONE element, the best thing you can do is ask for exactly one element and then cancel the upstream. There is no any 'waiting stop' if you just need one element: once you got it, you are done with the upstream.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason but it is possible that for example between your source and your `next` operator there is a `filter` which drops most of the items and it would result in a lot of back and forth to get that one item if it could request only one at a time.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi that's an interesting point, but it seems that this should be the responsibility of a 'possibly-dropping' operator (like `filter`) to variate the demand to avoid reducing the pattern to 'one by one', and not of any other operators that should neither know nor care about 'who is their upstream neighbor'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr - Requesting only what you need is usually ideal in a pull based system, but is very rarely ideal in a push based system.**

> I had an impression that reactive backpressure was about only asking for what you are ready to consume.

Not quite, it's what you are *able* to consume. The difference is subtle, but important.

In a pull based system, you'd be entirely correct - requesting more values than you know you'll ever need would almost never be a good thing, as the more values you request, the more work needs to happen to produce those values.

But note that reactive streams are inherently push based, not pull based. Most reactive frameworks, reactor included, are built with this in mind - and while hybrid, or pull based semantics are possible (using `Flux.generate()` to produce elements one at a time on demand for example) this is very much a secondary use case. The norm is to have a publisher that has a bunch of data it needs to offload, and it "wants" to push that to you as quickly as possible to be rid of it.

This is important as it flips the view as to what's ideal from a requesting perspective. It no longer becomes a question of "What's the most I'll ever need", but instead "What's the most I can ever deal with" - the bigger the number, the better.

As an example, let's say I have a database query returning 2000 records connected to a flux - but I only want 1. If I have a publisher that's pushing these 2000 records, and I call `request(1)`, then I'm not "helping" things at all - I haven't caused less processing on the database side, those records are already there and waiting. Since I've only requested 1 however, the publisher must then decide whether it can buffer the remaining records, or it's best to skip some or all of them, or it should throw an exception if it can't keep up, or something else entirely. Whatever it does, I'm actually causing *more* work, and possibly even an exception in some cases, by requesting *fewer* records.

Granted, this is not *always* desirable - perhaps those extra elements in the Flux really do cause extra processing that's wasteful, perhaps network bandwidth is a primary concern, etc. In that case, you'd want to explicitly call `limitRequest()`. In most cases though, that's probably not the behaviour you're after.

(For completeness sake, the *best* scenario is of course to limit the data at source - put a `LIMIT 1` on your database query if you only want a single value for instance. Then you don't have to worry about any of this stuff. But, of course, in real-world usage that's not always possible.)